# Get the types of the keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, types

Is there a "clean" way to take the type of the keys of a dictionary in python3?

For example, I want to decide if one of this dictionaries has keys of type `str`:

```
d1 = { 1:'one', 2:'two', 5:'five' }
d2 = { '1':'one', '2':'two', '5':'five' }
```

There is several ways to achieve this, for example, using some as:

```
isinstance(list(d2.keys())[0], type('str'))
```

But this is quite annoying because `d2.keys()` is not indexable, so you need to convert it into a list just to extract the value of one element of the list and check the type.

So has python3 something as `get_key_type(d2)`?
If not, is there a better (cleaner) way to ask if the key of a dictionary is of type `str`?

Comment: `<class 'dict_keys'>` is the type of d1.keys() so i hope that you got my point

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question itself. Instead, upvote/accept the correct answer (like you already did).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If i understood your question right, the cleanest way i know to get types of all keys in a dict is :

```
types1 = [type(k) for k in d1.keys()]
types2 = [type(k) for k in d2.keys()]
```

or if you want to have all the unique types you can use:

```
types1 = set(type(k) for k in d1.keys())
types2 = set(type(k) for k in d2.keys())
```

like that you'll know if there is a single or multiple types. (Thanks @Duncan)

this returns lists with types of keys found in respective dicts:

o/p:

```
[<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>]
[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]
```

However, if you're asking about the type of `d2.keys()` it's:

```
<class 'dict_keys'>
```

Hope this was somehow helpful.

Comment: Ok, your answer shows me that I had a concept error. In python a dictionary can mix keys of several types, so you can have ```d1 = { 1:'one', '2':'two'}``` and there is no way to check "the type of the key", but "the types of the keys"

Comment: oh now I see your point, yeah your comment is right, here is a [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) that may also help.

Comment: Better might be: `type1 = set(type(k) for k in d1)` and the same for d2. Then you can quickly determine whether all keys are one type or any key is the desired type.

Comment: The answer of @Duncan open many nice pieces of code as: "Select the entries in the dictionary whose key is of type('str')" ```{k:d[k] for k in d if type(k) == type('str')}```. Another good one is: "How to convert all keys in the dictionary to type str": ```{str(k):d[k] for k in d }```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to find out if your dictionary has only string keys you could simply use:

```
>>> set(map(type, d1)) == {str}
False

>>> set(map(type, d2)) == {str}
True
```

The `set(map(type, ...))` creates a set that contains the different types of your dictionary keys:

```
>>> set(map(type, d2))
{str}
>>> set(map(type, d1))
{int}
```

And `{str}` is a literal that creates a set containing the type `str`. The equality check works for sets and gives `True` if the sets contain exactly the same items and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`d1.keys()` returns `<class 'dict_keys'>` type objects which is iterable but you can not index it like lists

```
>>> d1 = { 1:'one', 2:'two', 5:'five' }
>>> d1.keys
<built-in method keys of dict object at 0x7f59bc897288>
>>> d1.keys()
dict_keys([1, 2, 5])
>>> type(d1.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>
>>> [i for i in d1.keys()]
[1, 2, 5]
>>> [i for i in d1.keys() if isinstance(i, int)]
[1, 2, 5]
```

Also just repeating what you said

```
>>> d1.keys()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

Also Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) out

Comment: You are right saying d1.keys() is iterable, so I have corrected the question. But you don't answer how to determine the type of each value of d1.keys() without converting it into a list, then extracting a value, then checking the type.