# How do I check, if every key in a dictionary is an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I just recently started coding with python and I came across an exercise, where you need to work with dictionaries. I specifically struggle with the part of the exercise, where I need to check, if every key in the dictionary has the type int.

Comment: What's the difficulty, checking if an object is an int, or checking a condition for each key in a dictionary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the types of the keys in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037977/get-the-type-of-the-key-of-a-dictionary)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing code for what you've tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts

Answer (score 6):

How about :

```
# returns True if each key in x is an instance of type int, else returns False
all(isinstance(key, int) for key in x.keys())
```

where x is your dictionary